# Identifying reference systems from coordinates in WKT string?

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg

I have these polygons in WKT string that represent an area in Florence (Italy), but I don't know what reference system coordinate is.

First polygon

```
POLYGON((11.262552738189697 43.77163613277955,11.257896423339844 43.774301152286796,11.25349760055542 43.775633617505264,11.249699592590332 43.77368139090623,11.247274875640867 43.77095436452717,11.245450973510742 43.767653876522246,11.247982978820799 43.76464763976463,11.252360343933105 43.76670863279483,11.253819465637207 43.76532947990529,11.254441738128662 43.76435320639226,11.257338523864746 43.76398128848206,11.25817537307739 43.76422923401245,11.26323938369751 43.771605143482134,11.262552738189697 43.77163613277955))
```

Also the second polygon is in Florence

```
POLYGON (( 1681286.81126823415979743 4850128.89515804499387741, 1682031.93321837158873677 4850395.01014023739844561, 1682797.57793015497736633 4849317.41856242809444666, 1682803.66666672844439745 4848914.74555179476737976, 1682614.05974191660061479 4848429.08570929430425167, 1682344.61832244717516005 4848196.23509987629950047, 1681739.20673796045593917 4847983.34311412274837494, 1681513.00900309719145298 4848016.60748689621686935, 1681193.67102446686476469 4847827.00056208483874798, 1680754.58130385004915297 4847727.20744376257061958, 1680495.11919621285051107 4847753.81894198153167963, 1680398.65251516830176115 4848399.14777379762381315, 1680258.94214951759204268 4848542.1845767255872488, 1680338.77664417517371476 4848821.60530802700668573, 1680372.04101694910787046 4848997.90648372936993837, 1680774.53992751450277865 4848794.99380980804562569, 1680638.15599914104677737 4849047.80304289050400257, 1680142.51684480858966708 4849573.38013271987438202, 1680872.05598999722860754 4849910.05710198264569044, 1680859.48633611970581114 4849965.36357904318720102, 1680870.38003614684566855 4849977.9332329211756587, 1680810.8836744602303952 4850102.79179477039724588, 1680789.09627440595068038 4850098.60191014502197504, 1680765.63292050128802657 4850152.23243335541337729, 1680808.36974368477240205 4850175.69578726030886173, 1680826.80523603828623891 4850163.12613338232040405, 1680905.57506700372323394 4850235.19214894622564316, 1680907.25102085410617292 4850236.03012587130069733, 1680895.5193439016584307 4850255.30359515082091093, 1680929.03842090838588774 4850278.7669490547850728, 1680974.28917486732825637 4850273.73908750433474779, 1680975.96512871747836471 4850255.30359515082091093, 1681076.52235973719507456 4850254.46561822574585676, 1681088.25403668964281678 4850275.41504135448485613, 1681132.6668137232773006 4850294.68851063307374716, 1681146.91242145118303597 4850241.05798742268234491, 1681128.47692909743636847 4850222.62249506916850805, 1681174.56565998145379126 4850100.27786399517208338, 1681190.48722155974246562 4850095.25000244379043579, 1681286.81126823415979743 4850128.89515804499387741))
```

It has another reference system and I have to convert it to the format of the first polygon area in Florence.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2):

The first polygon is most probably WGS 84 = EPSG 4326.

You can see in the attached image the coordinates of the city.
[image]

The 2nd polygons appears to be in Monte Mario / Italy zone 1, or EPSG 3003

Comment: thanks for your support. I have edited my question because I have a 2 polygon. I don't know what reference system it use, but I have to convert it to the EPSG 4326 like the first polygon. Can you help me ?

Comment: @michele I've edited my Answer, it appears that your 2nd polygon is in a local Italian TM grid

Comment: thanks @HDunn yes these polygon are near Florence. I have to convert the second shape to the first reference system... How can I do?

Comment: Try "conversion between coordinate systems" or "how to project another coordinate system" in google. It is as useful as the stack exchange.